# Weback is reloading but not updating

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Is there any method to make webpack reload like in create-react-app?

Now i have reloading page instead of updating page

Links:
to package.json: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-murdock-hzl493?file=/src/index.js
to webpack.config: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-poitras-2cp859?file=/src/index.js

I tried:
change `webpack-dev-server` to `webpack serve`,
use `--hot in` script instead of `hot: true` in config (this preserve reloading, but here no updating either),
make `target: "web"` in config,
set `liveReload: false`